# If Google uses discriminatory language, how can I report it and log a complaint?

Tags: discrimination, human-rights

I have been asked *what race I belong to* by a Google Service registration online form at https://io.google/2022.

After some time researching, I haven't found any where to log a complaint directly to Google about it.

How can I proceed in order to remove/change the discriminatory content and how do I proceed, in order to take it further if Google keeps it online?

The only way I have found is from here:
https://support.google.com/code/contact/cloud_platform_report
and here:
https://about.google/intl/en_in/contact-google/
but these are only accepting the complaints as "feedback".

I would like to know if I need to get a lawyer for this or if I can do it by myself.

[image: I/O registration form]

I know that many have done the same mistake, but while ethnicities are many, the human race is one.

Comment: In what way is asking for a race identification discriminatory? Is Google stating that you will not be allowed access if you identify with a specific race? Have you tried the support link [here](https://about.google/intl/en_in/contact-google/)?

Comment: @doneal24 I have added a screenshot. Please add your precious suggestion as an answer.

Comment: @doneal24, to ask what race a human belongs to is racist, not just discriminatory. There is only one human race. Do not divide it.

Comment: If you look [here](https://sitn.hms.harvard.edu/flash/2017/science-genetics-reshaping-race-debate-21st-century/) you'll see that authorities might not agree with your clear-cut distinction. Race might be mostly a social construct but biological ancestry does define certain traits that are measurable and distinctive.

Comment: While asking the question could lead to illegal discrimination I do not see what law it breaks to ask, especially with and opt-out.  From your profile I see you are in AU. Is your view of human rights codified into law there?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite, it breaks the law the same way a question like this breaks it: <<Do you know that there are many human races?>> or <<Which human race are you?>>

Comment: @GeorgeWhite also the following question is not "just" a question: <<Are you a slave or a master?>>, in this case, since slavery is illegal, the question is illegal.

Comment: It is rare that any legal system makes any question illegal. Can you point to a law in AU or anywhere else that makes asking those question illegal ? The closest I can think of is that some questions are not proper for employers to ask job applicants. A question that one can't ask a job applicant might be perfectly legal in other contexts. I think you are confusing enforcing slavery with talking about slavery. One is illegal the other is not in locations where citizens are generally free to speak their minds.

Comment: Google is International and needs to remove the word *race* from the question and leave *ethnicity*

Comment: I think you need to have a long and hard look at the definition of “race”. Notice how the distinction between “race” as it is used in this form and “human race” is made right at the top https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_(human_categorization)

Comment: The OP is asking how one can log a complaint, not whether the complaint has any substance. Whether it does or does not have substance is a separate question (it doesn't).

Comment: You'll definitely need a lawyer for this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is Law SE. We answer legal questions. We don’t answer customer service questions.

Comment: So what happens when an International service makes this question appear on my screen in Australia (in my house), directed to me (Australian citizen):<<What caste do you belong to?>> (FYI caste is an illegal practice if you didn't notice, like racism)

Answer (score 1):

With the extra information from your screenshot, it looks like Google is using the information to understand the audience's diversity. No discriminatory action is implied. It also gives you an opt-out for disclosing the racial information. I don't see that there is any basis for complaint to Google.

Comment: There is only one race. The human race is one, only racists (and ignorants), want to split it.

Comment: @Mau Would you prefer either of the terms `deme` or `ecotype`? These are scientifically [accepted](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3737365/) alternatives.

Comment: I need help to take this further legally, thanks

Comment: @Mau I wish you well. There are (US) federal requirements to collect demographic data for federally-funded programs. Private institutions (like Alphabet) are certainly within their rights to ask for the same information as long as they don't discriminate on legally-protected classes.

Comment: FYI, while ethnicities are many, the human race is one.

Comment: The OP is asking how one can log a complaint, not whether the complaint has any substance. Whether it does or does not have substance is a separate question (it doesn't).

Comment: I've flagged this as "not an answer" as it does not address the question posed by the OP

Answer (score 1):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

[42 USC 2000a](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/2000a) states

> (a) All persons shall be entitled to the full and equal enjoyment of
> the goods, services, facilities, privileges, advantages, and
> accommodations of any place of public accommodation, as defined in
> this section, without discrimination or segregation on the ground of
> race, color, religion, or national origin.

If a website is a place of public accommodation, racial discrimination would be prohibited. This question has not been decided by SCOTUS. In [Gil v. Winn-Dixie Stores, Inc.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=1847911369587013563&hl=en&as_sdt=6&as_vis=1&oi=scholarr), the 11th Circuit ruled that a website is not per se a place of public accommodation, as defined by the ADA (a different law prohibiting discrimination). On the face of it, racial discrimination on a website especially one that has no connection to a physical location is not prohibited. You would file a complaint with the Department of Justice, alleging illegal discrimination. You can be assured that they will at least read your complaint.

Answer (score 1):

### There is no illegality here

First, discrimination is not, *in general*, illegal. Only specific forms of discrimination in specific circumstances are illegal.

Second, asking is not discrimination. Asking for information on race, gender etc. does not imply discrimination on that basis.

Third, Google is clearly not discriminating on the basis of race. They clearly state that they are seeking demographic information for purposes that are clearly not discriminatory.

Fourth, you don’t have to provide the information if you don’t want to.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137267/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-if-google-uses-discriminatory-language-how-can-i).